# Why does "pip install <package name> " and "pip -v " shut down my computer?

Tags: python, windows, pip, package

I have used pip install many times to import packages such as numpy, matplotlib, etc. with no problem.  A couple months ago I updated python and attempted to install a package (I forget which one) and it shut down my computer.  Since then I have uninstalled and reinstalled both pip and python multiple times only to get the same result.  Every pip command (help, version, etc..) shuts down my computer instantly.  I am fairly new to python, and I am using a dell computer with windows 10.

side note: Python still functions fine on my computer.

Comment: I'd check the pip binary

Comment: And the system logs to see why it shutdown.

Comment: Ok, how exactly do i check the pip binary and what am i looking for?  ( sorry, my only programming experience is in Matlab other than a few months of teaching myself python)